# copy method of util class is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am having a class Employee as:

```
public class Employee
{
    public var name:String;
    public function Employee(name:String)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to create copy of an `ArrayCollection` of employees using `ObjectUtil` as:

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var newEmployees = ObjectUtil.copy(employees);
    for each(var emp:Employee in newEmployees) {
        Alert.show(emp.name);
    }

}
```

But it is throwing exception:

> Main Thread (Suspended: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed:
>   cannot convert Object@ef41a19 to objectutil.Employee.)
>     objectutil::ObjectUtilCopyCheck/button1_clickHandler
>     objectutil::ObjectUtilCopyCheck/___ObjectUtilCopyCheck_Button1_click

Can anyone identify what is wrong here? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `copy` internally makes copy using native serialization technique:

```
public static function copy(value:Object):Object
{
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    buffer.writeObject(value);
    buffer.position = 0;
    var result:Object = buffer.readObject();
    return result;
}
```

If we use remoting tag then it is easy. For example:

```
//assume employee has [RemoteClass] metadata. 
var newEmployees = Employee (ObjectUtil.copy(emp));
```

Else you need to register this class as (assuming that com.app.vo.Employee is the package of class Employee ):

```
registerClassAlias("com.app.vo.Employee",Employee);
//Now we can copy and caste
var newEmployees = Employee (ObjectUtil.copy(emp));
```

Hope this will help you.